# How to insert variable types for table headers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

```
if object_id('tempdb..#mysql_cte1') is not null 
     drop table #mysql_cte1

create table #mysql_cte1
(
     DateTime datetime, ' + 
     quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'TickerID')) + ' int, ' +
     quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'TickerID')) + ' int,' + 
     quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'Bid')) + ' float, ' + 
     quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'Ask')) + ',' + 
     quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'Bid')) + ' float,' +
     quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'Ask')) + ' float 
)
```

I have the above, which I would like the header to be named as:

```
DateTime|Coke TickerID |Coal TickerID |Coke Bid |Coke Ask |Coal Bid |Coal Ask
```

But when I used the above code, I will get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+quotename(Concat(@product, '.

Comment: Form a dynamic query and then execute is using "exec" or exec sp_executesql

Comment: So i guess you're saying:

set @mysql: '<my code above>

exec(@mysql)

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: However, after trying your method, I get this error:
Incorrect syntax near 'tempdb'

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to the question?

Comment: set @mysql1 = '
if object_id('tempdb..#mysql_cte1') is not null drop table #mysql_cte1
create table #mysql_cte1(DateTime datetime,'+quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'TickerID'))+' int,'+quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'TickerID'))+' int,'+quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'Bid'))+' float,'+quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'Ask'))+','+quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'Bid'))+' float,'+quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'Ask'))+' float)
'

exec(@mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query: I have fixed couple of things:

```
DECLARE @product varchar(100) = 'COKE'
DECLARE @product2 varchar(100) = 'Coal'
DECLARE @mysql varchar(max)
set @mysql = 'if object_id(''tempdb..#mysql_cte1'') is not null drop table #mysql_cte1 
          create table #mysql_cte1(DateTime datetime,'+quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'TickerID'))+' int,'+quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'TickerID'))+' int,'+quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'Bid'))+' float,'+quotename(Concat(@product, ' ', 'Ask'))+' float,'+quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'Bid'))+' float,'+quotename(Concat(@product2, ' ', 'Ask'))+' float) 
          SELECT * FROM #mysql_cte1'
           exec(@mysql)
```

Please note that for a column with name "Ask" I have added float as the type, you change the above query as per your needs

Comment: hey @Sujith, tried what you told me. Still gives me the same error :/

Comment: I could execute the query I have added in my answer above. Please copy paste as it is and run it and see.

Comment: Got it, after refreshing (: Cheers! Thank you.